# Problemas al implementar OnLongClickListener

Tags: java, android

El error:

> Error:(36, 10) error: reached end of file while parsing

sé que el error está al final, pero no consigo solucionarlo

Mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView logo_app;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));

        logo_app = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_app);

        logo_app.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Animation startRotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_image);
                logo_app.startAnimation(startRotateAnimation);
                return true;

            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Ese es tu código completo de la clase `MainActivity`?

Comment: Ese tipo de error suele referirse a que hay llaves `{` o paréntesis `(` abiertos que no se cierran debidamente, y desde luego en el código que incluyes faltan al menos dos llaves (una para cerrar el bloque del método y otra para cerrar la definición de la clase). ¿Es este todo el código completo del fichero?

Comment: ups esto parece un error tipográfico, es obvio que falta cerrar algunas estructuras... =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te faltan dos llaves `}`. La de cierre del `onCreate` y la del cierre de la clase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView logo_app;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));

        logo_app = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_app);

        logo_app.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Animation startRotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_image);
                logo_app.startAnimation(startRotateAnimation);
                return true;

            }
        }; //; aquí
   } // aquí
} // aquí también
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero lo que necesitaba finalmente era  }
        });
    }
}

Comment: Igualmente gracias por tu respuesta, no sé quien te dio -1, modificala con lo que te comento y la doy como útil @Naos

Comment: Te di +1 ya que tu respuesta es válida . Cuando se da -1 se debe dar el argumento!